# Run xpath queries against an offlline file?

Tags: python, xpath

I have scraped the full html of a webpage and saved it as information.txt

*Is there a simple (if any) method to run xpath queries against this locally saved txt file?* I do not wish to run xpath queries against the online webpage (for various reasons).

My code so far had been;

```
from lxml import html
import requests

file = open('information.txt' , 'r')
file.seek(0)
target=file.read()
file.close

data1 = target.xpath('/html/body/p')
```

But the error message recieved was;

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getxpath.py", line 15, in <module>
    data1 = target.xpath('/html/body/p')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'xpath'
```

Answer (score 1):

R solution. 
Parse the file with *htmlParse* and request with *xpathSapply*. Functions comes with the package [XML](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html).